# Cannot set javascript innerhtml in IE 11 without compatibility view

Tags: javascript, ie-compatibility-mode

I am trying to correct an HTML form that works in IE11 compatibility view but behaves differently if not in compatibility.

The user can change the values in the form input elements and then click Save.

The Save button grabs the innerhtml of the entire page and stores it into a hidden input element, then proceeds to submit the form. In CV mode, the innerhtml contains the edits the user made. When NOT in CV mode, the innerhtml is the original rendering.

How can I collect the new values in the fields?

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function saveit() {
    var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("html1").setAttribute("value", markup);
    document.htmlform.submit();
   }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>

  <form name="htmlform" id="htmlform" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="html1" id="html1"><br>
  <input type="text" name="batch_num" id="batch_num" value="100"><br>
  <input type="text" name="batch_name" id="batch_name" value="Start"><br>
  </form>
  <input type="button" name="savebutton" value="Save" onclick="saveit();">

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that works without compatibility mode? I say, `innerHTML` returns all rendered HTML inside an element, but the user interactions doesn't be returned. So this will not work on any browser. What is the error you get?

Comment: The form is submitted to a page that stores the values to the database, including the HTML to reproduce the page. In CV, user edits are present; non-CV, the original values are present.

Comment: User inputs should never be included in the result of `innerHTML`. If CV is including them, that's a bug in CV, every other browser is doing it correctly.

Comment: Also, the way to set the value of a hidden input is with `document.getElementById("html1").value = ...`, not with `.setAttribute`.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? When you submit the form, the user inputs will be in their appropriate input parameters, why are you looking in the HTML for them?

Comment: Originally it used the `.value=` format, the `setAttribute` was an attempted workaround that also did not work. The users print the form, once when creating it and optionally retrieving from the database to reprint at a later time.